# Add / remove user from AD group automatically

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have some softwares integrated with AD group, so I usually need to maintain the members of c AD groups. 
Almost theses operations are temporary, maybe 24hr or 1 month,etc.

Can I use powershell or vb script or other programs to make these routine done by program?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use PowerShell (or VB).

Add users to an AD Group with PowerShell using `Add-ADGroupMember` and remove them using `Remove-ADGroupMember`.

I would create a Scheduled Task running your script every hour or so.